# link excel columns

Tags: excel, function

I'm trying to link 2 lists similar to this:

List 1

```
 A        B 
0001   Company A
0002   Company B
```

List 2

```
 A        B
0002   email1
0001   email2
```

I want the output to be like this:

```
 A        B          C
0001   Company A   email2
0002   Company B   email1
```

What excel function should I use?

Comment: You can use a combination of `MATCH` and `INDEX`, as explained [here](http://exceluser.com/blog/465/excels-best-lookup-method-index-match.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given,

List 1

```
 A        B 
0001   Company A
0002   Company B
```

List 2

```
 D        E
0002   email1
0001   email2
```

In column `C` (cell `C1`) put:

`=VLOOKUP(D1,D1:E2,2,FALSE)`

and copy it vertically to as many cells as needed.

You should end up with

```
 A        B          C        D       E
0001   Company A   email2   0002   email1
0002   Company B   email1   0001   email2
```

To explain a bit about `VLOOKUP`:

`VLOOKUP(lookup value or cell containing value, table with values to match against, column of table to return value from, find exact match (TRUE or FALSE))`